# Ubuntu 20.04.1 Keeps Disabling One of My Displays

Tags: nvidia, sound, 20.04, display

I recently asked a very similar question in relation to 18.04.5, and upgraded to 20.04.1 and am experiencing the same issue.

I am curious about why Ubuntu keeps disabling one of my displays.

Currently I am running 4 displays, 3 Dell monitors and a Samsung TV.

If the computer locks and turns off the display connections and the TV shuts itself off after x amount of time , or if I manually turn the TV off, whenever I turn it back on, whether before waking Ubuntu, or after, the screen stays disabled and I have to go into display settings and turn it back on. Which in turn causes me to lose the resolution setting that I had it on.

This is on a fresh install + update + installing NVIDIA drivers.

The difference now is that I also lose audio sometimes and need to enable the monitor, disable it, then enable it again to get my sound back.

This is quite frustrating.

I am running an NVIDIA 1070 and AMD Ryzen 5 2600, the three monitors are on DisplayPort while the TV is running over HDMI.

I am using the recommended drivers for NVIDIA (450.66) using `ubuntu-drivers devices` and `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Short of this issue, everything else works great.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? The same thing is happening to me with Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't, given that was also almost 3 years ago to the day haha. I've since upgraded my machine and am down to just using an ultra wide monitor. Running Plex for any streaming stuff, so I rarely hook into my TV anymore, and when I do I just plug the cable in and remove it when I'm done.